# PostgreSQL. Как удалить все данные из таблицы большого размера?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Есть таблица (назовем ее `logs`). В ней скопилось **33GB** записей. Необходимо ее очистить. Пытался делать

```
DELETE FROM logs
```

Но спустя какое-то время после запуска команды в выводе отобразилось, что удалено N-ое (число было большим) кол-во строк, но размер таблицы остался прежним (полагаю, количество строк также не изменилось). Впервые столкнулся с такой задачей и не знаю, что с этим делать.

Собственно, вопрос: как можно удалить все данные из таблицы `logs`?

---

У таблицы есть только Primary Key, индексов нет.

Comment: Закон подлости: сидел 2 часа не мог найти ответ, и вот спустя 10 минут после того, как задал вопрос, нашел его... Использовал `TRUNCATE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если необходимо удалить именно всё - то нужен `truncate`.

`delete` никогда не возвращает дисковое пространство напрямую. PostgreSQL - MVCC база, `delete` только отмечает строку удалённой. Затем приходит `autovacuum` (либо вручную вызывается `vacuum`), который вычищает из файлов таблицы мёртвые, никому более недоступные версии строк. В конце работы `vacuum` проверяет, нет ли в конце таблицы страниц данных, в которых не осталось строк. Если есть - то пробует усечь размер таблицы. Размеры индексов сами никогда не уменьшаются (для этого нужен `reindex`). Сверх того радости добавляет, что все эти операции пишутся в wal в полном объёме.

`truncate` же просто выделяет новые пустые датафайлы и удаляет старые. Поэтому для задачи очистить всё - несравнимо эффективнее. Хотя и требует эксклюзивную блокировку.